# How could I create this dictionary who's values are coming from a DataFrame faster?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have this dataframe:

| event | attendees | duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| meeting | [{"id":1, "email": "email1"}, {"id":2, "email": "email2"}] | 3600 |
| lunch | [{"id":2, "email": "email2"}, {"id":3, "email": "email3"}] | 7200 |

Which I am trying to turn into this dictionary:

```
{
    email1: {
       'num_events_with': 1,
       'duration_of_events': 3600,
    },
    email2: {
       'num_events_with': 2,
       'duration_of_events': 10,800,
    },
    email3: {
       'num_events_with': 1,
       'duration_of_events': 7200,
    },
}
```

except in my case the dataframe has thousands of rows and the dictionary I'm creating uses multiple columns to get the results for the dictionary keys so I need to be able to access the information that is relevant to each user email while creating the dictionary.

The purpose of the dictionary is to give information about the people the user has been in events with. So the first dictionary key is saying that the user has been in 1 event with email1 which lasted 3600 seconds.

Here is my approach to getting this dictionary:

```
# need to sort because I use diff() later
df.sort_values(by='startTime', ascending=True, inplace=True)

# a list of all contacts (emails) that have been in events with user
contacts = contacts_in_events
contact_info_dict = {}
df['attendees_str'] = df['attendees'].astype(str)

for contact in contacts:
    temp_df = df[df['attendees_str'].str.contains(contact)]
    duration_of_events = temp_df['duration'].sum()
    num_events_with = len(temp_df.index)

    contact_info_dict[contact] = {
        'duration_of_events': duration_of_events,
        'num_events_with': num_events_with
    }
```

but this is too slow. Any ideas for how to do this in a different way that would be faster?

This is the output of the actual dataframe .to_dict('records'):

```
{
 'creator': {
            'displayName': None,
            'email': 'creator of event',
            'id': None,
            'self': None
  },
  'start': {
            'date': None,
            'dateTime': '2022-09-13T12:30:00-04:00',
            'timeZone': 'America/Toronto'
  },
  'end': {
          'date': None,
          'dateTime': '2022-09-13T13:00:00-04:00',
          'timeZone': 'America/Toronto'
   },
  'attendees': [
       {
        'comment': None,
        'displayName': None,
        'email1': 'email1@email.com',
        'responseStatus': 'accepted'
       },
       {
        'comment': None,
        'displayName': None,
        'email': 'email2@email.com',
        'responseStatus': 'accepted'
       }
  ],
  'summary': 'One on One Meeting',
  'description': '...',
  'calendarType': 'work',
  'startTime': Timestamp('2022-09-13 16:30:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
  'endTime': Timestamp('2022-09-13 17:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
  'eventDuration': 1800.0,
  'dowStart': 1.0,
  'endStart': 1.0,
  'weekday': True,
  'startTOD': 59400,
  'endTOD': 61200,
  'day': Period('2022-09-13', 'D')
}
```

Comment: please provide the output of df.to_dict()` list for your example, your "dictionaries" seem to have an invalid syntax

Comment: Did my last edit fix the syntax? Otherwise I'm not sure what you're referring to.

Comment: For clarity and reproducibility it's always best to provide a DataFrame constructor (or dictionary). Try to run `df.to_dict()` and provide the output.

Comment: Okay I just updated the post with one of the records from to_dict('records')

Comment: Hmm… seems a different format than the provided example. Anyway, check my answer below and see if this works for you

Comment: Your solution works great and is faster than my original code. I am just wondering about the use of .pipe in your code. Could you please tell me why this method is used and not .apply or something? Is there a reason .pipe specifically makes this code run as expected?

Comment: `pipe` is not strictly required. This is just a helper method to avoid doing `df = f(df)`, instead: `df.pipe(f)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) 'attendees' to individual rows, then convert to columns with [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html), aggregate the data with [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) and convert  [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
out = (df
   .explode('attendees', ignore_index=True)
   .pipe(lambda d: d.join(pd.json_normalize(d.pop('attendees'))))
   .groupby('email')
   .agg(**{'num_events_with': ('email', 'count'),
           'duration_of_events': ('duration', 'sum')
          })
   .to_dict(orient='index')
)
```

Output:

```
{'email1': {'num_events_with': 1, 'duration_of_events': 3600},
 'email2': {'num_events_with': 2, 'duration_of_events': 10800},
 'email3': {'num_events_with': 1, 'duration_of_events': 7200}}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Example**

```
col = ['event', 'attendees', 'duration']
data = [['meeting', [{"id":1, "email": "email1"}, {"id":2, "email": "email2"}], 3600], ['lunch', [{"id":2, "email": "email2"}, {"id":3, "email": "email3"}],7200]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=col)
```

---

**Code**

```
df1 = df.explode('attendees')
grouper = df1['attendees'].str['email']
col1 = ['num_events_with', 'duration_of_events']
out = (df1.groupby(grouper)['duration'].agg(['count', sum]).T.set_axis(col1).to_dict())
```

`out`:

```
{'email1': {'num_events_with': 1, 'duration_of_events': 3600},
 'email2': {'num_events_with': 2, 'duration_of_events': 10800},
 'email3': {'num_events_with': 1, 'duration_of_events': 7200}}
```

if you want 1 line use following

```
(df.explode('attendees').assign(attendees=lambda x:x['attendees'].str['email'])
 .groupby('attendees')['duration'].agg(['count',sum])
 .T.set_axis(['num_events_with', 'duration_of_events']).to_dict())
```